# Is this approach okay to prevent repeat of actions?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter script which user is redirected to a form and returned, after returning, **only 1 time** something (a Financial Transaction using external API) should be sent to user.

At first all I did was flag if it's completed (`UPDATE table SET completed = 1 WHERE id = X`)

and before sending I checked with `if(intval($completed) === 1){//STOP SENDING}`.

But then I thought what if they open the page multiple times too quickly (accidentally or manually or using other methods), so here is what I did:

#### Method of Question:

I added a new table in database, using a Unique Key (order ID) , before sending the thing to user I insert a row in this table, if it was inserted (I check with CodeIgniter's `$this->db->affected_rows() > 0`) I send it, if not (Duplicate Unique Key prevents inserting multiple times) then I stop sending.

> Is this approach okay to make sure it won't be sent twice to the user?

#### Edit:

Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, this thing I talk about (that should be sent to user only 1 time) isn't a message, it is some kind of financial transaction sent to user using another API.

Comment: Do pay extremely close attention to race conditions as this could be a situation where you're exposed to one. If that `UPDATE` statement didn't update any rows, you've already done that transaction and you should stop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a variable that exists only on the **next time** the user enters a page you better use [`flashdata`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata):

> CodeIgniter supports “flashdata”, or session data that will only be available for the next request, and is then automatically cleared.

Both codeigniter 2 and codeigniter 3 support:

```
// set data
$this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'value');
// get data
$this->session->flashdata('item');
```

Comment: Based on the variable inside your `flashdata` you can decide to run a code, and it will run only one time (because that variable will be removed after that time)

Comment: Are you sure CI flashdata is a better approach and safe enough to prevent duplicate financial transactions? (what if they load at exact time using 2 devices with the same IP and user agent, or i dunno similar hacking methods)

Comment: If you are working with financial transactions I would go with some locking mechanism (it can be DB based). As for the `flashdata` of codeigniter - haven't checked their code, but I guess they read and delete the value immediately from the session, so it should work as well (however I don't think they implement any locking there, is if that's your case I would think about it twice).